# Write from text file of integers in mongodb for sorting and find distance

Tags: arrays, mongodb, algorithm

I have a text file that includes integer numbers, and it has 1m rows. I want compute the number of target values `t` in the interval `[-10000,10000]` such that there are distinct numbers `x,y` in the input file that satisfy `x+y=t`.

I guess if I can write this data in MongoDB and next sort them, maybe I can find a solution, that show the items which their sum is between `[-10000,10000]` but I can't save each row of the file in MongoDB.
can someone help me in this?

Comment: Can you elaborate the algorithm part with an example?

Comment: Why do you need MongoDB? One integer takes 4 bytes, then 1M of them is 4MB, modern computers have at least 4GB Ram and therefore you can hold all the numbers in a simple array and perform any algorithm. If you need an idea for the algorithm itself I'd be happy to help.

Comment: you are right but for a future stream of data, I want to save the data.